# Calculated Fields with nestTables Option for MySQL Query in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using the 'nestTables' option in the code below to separate the data returned from an SQL query into their respective tables.  I am also including a calculated field in my query that I would like to include in the primary table.

As an example, I am executing the following route:

```
router.route('/person/:personId').get(function(req,res){
    var person_id = req.params.personId;
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(503).send({ result: false, error: 'CONNECTION error: ' + err.code});
        } else {
            var sqlString='SELECT *, someField - 1 as calculated FROM person LEFT JOIN person_status ON person.id = person_status.person_id WHERE person.id = ' + person_id;
            var options={sql:sqlString,nestTables:true};
            connection.query(options, function(error, rows, fields) {
                connection.release();

                var nestingOptions = [
                    {tableName: 'person', pkey:'id'},
                    {tableName: 'person_status', pkey:'id', fkeys:[{table:'person',col:'person_id'}]}
                ];

                if (error) {
                    return res.status(500).send({ result: false, error: 'QUERY ERROR: ' + error.code});
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).send(rows);                 
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and I am receiving the following JSON Response:

```
[
  {
    "person": {
      "id": 1,
      other person data . . . 
      "person_status": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          other data . . . 
        }
      ]
    },
    "person_status": {
      "id": 3,
      other data . . . 
    },
    "": {
      "calculated": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Ideally, I would like to include the calculated field into the person subgroup as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "person": {
      "id": 1,
      "calculated": 0
      other person data . . . 
      "person_status": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          other data . . . 
        }
      ]
    },
    "person_status": {
      "id": 3,
      other data . . . 
    }
  }
]
```

Is there any way that I can include the calculated field into the person table,  or is there a better solution that fits this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options to solve this, one dirty way using SQL:

```
var sqlString = 'SELECT *, someField - 1 as calculated FROM person WHERE person.id=?';
sqlString = 'SELECT * FROM (' + sqlString + ') as person';
sqlString += ' LEFT JOIN person_status ON person.id = person_status.person_id';
var options={sql:sqlString, nestTables:true};
connection.query(options, [person_id], function(error, rows, fields) {
```

and the obvious solution using js:

```
var sqlString = 'SELECT *, someField - 1 as calculated FROM person LEFT JOIN person_status ON person.id = person_status.person_id WHERE person.id=?';
var options = {sql:sqlString, nestTables:true};
connection.query(options, [person_id], function(error, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.person.calculated = row[''].calculated;
    delete row[''];
  });
```

I don't think there is a more pleasant solution for this. I even checked if there is a possibility to trick the FieldPacket or RowDataPacket parser but didn't see a way to fake a table name (without monkey patching the mysql driver).

Comment: Thanks user3173842, I have tested both cases and they equally work.  Out of interest, which of these methods would be considered the most efficient? I'm tempted to go with the second solution, but not sure if there is a great cost with the forEach loop.

Comment: The cost is comparatively low so if you are only selecting a few hundred rows or less there should be no measurable difference. MySQL will probably be a little more efficient. The first option requires some RAM on the database side, the second one generates CPU load on the node.js side, so if there are separate servers I would choose the way that uses the system where I have more resources available - since the output is the same it's even easy to switch at any time.